# React-router-redux push action is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to navigate to Main page once authentication is successful, I am using redux-saga for making API calls. Below is my login generator function:

```
 import * as Type from '../actions/types';
import { takeLatest, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';


function* loginUser(action) {
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    try{
        console.log(action.user);
        const result = yield call([auth, auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword], action.user.email, action.user.password);
        console.log('login sucess');
        yield put({type: Type.AUTH_SUCCESSFULL, user: action.user, authMessage:'Login Success'});
        console.log('done');  //being logged
        yield put(push('/home')); /not being redirected to home. Even the browser url is not changing
        console.log('pushed'); //being logged
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error.message);
      yield put({type: Type.AUTH_FAILED, errorMessage: error.message});
    }
 }
```

I just installed react-router-redux and tried doing this, Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue here. Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and following is my solution. Code you have added has not an issue. You need do some extra works to make this work.

**Reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { History } from 'history'

const redusers = {
  ...
}

const mainReducer = (history: History) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  ...redusers
})

export default mainReducer;
```

**Store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'

import mainReducer from './mainReducer';
import rootSaga from './rootSaga';

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

const configureStore = (preloadedState?: any) => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const store = createStore(
    mainReducer(history),
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), logger, sagaMiddleware),
  );
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import configureStore, { history } from './store';

const store = configureStore();
const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App history={history} />
    </Provider>
);
```

**App.js** - only added necessary code lines bellow

```
...
import { History } from 'history'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
...

const {history} = props;
...

return(){
   ...
   <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      {routes}
   </ConnectedRouter>
   ...
}
```

After setting up above things on your app, it will work as you want.

The other thing is we are no longer using BrowserHistory in the app because custom history has implemented.